# WordPress SEO by Yoast - Facebook thumbnail issue

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, wordpress

I use this plugin on a site and it gives out wrong facebook thumbnail despite selecting facebook image in the setting of the page.

site URL: http://www.artsnaplesworldfestival.org/

After going through the facebook debugger tool: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/
I found out the tags which were responsible for facebook thumbnail are being generated in the  section of the page rather than  section.

Facebook uses og:image tag to use the image as thumbnail and this tag is in the , it should be in

Does anybody know how to fix this? is there a way where I can change the location of tabs from  to

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, there was nothing wrong with the plugin - the theme was coded wrongly, the ending  tag was up in the wrong place. It now works nicely.